# In HSQLDB, why is it necessary to drop schema in the "After" method i.e., after the test is completed?

Tags: java, unit-testing, integration-testing, hsqldb

Hey I am writing some unit tests and integration tests using HSQLDB as the database. In the tests, it is recommended to drop the schema's after each unit or integration test. Wont the tables get deleted on their own once test is completed? Or is this done to prevent errors during build time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the scope of your HSQLDB instance. If you create one per test and then discard it after the test completes then dropping the schema is redundant but the likelihood is that many devs are not explicitly aware of (or even want to care about) the lifecycle of the HSQLDB instance being used by their test cases hence the recommendation to drop the schema after test completion.

The goal is test independence; if you drop the schema (or use `TRUNCATE SCHEMA <schema_name> AND COMMIT;`) after each test then you can be confident that data inserted or mutated by `TestA` will not trip up `TestB` etc.

Of course, test independence could also be achieved by:

- Ensuring that each test runs in a transaction which is rolled back on completion
- Ensuring that each test uses a dedicated HSQLDB instance which is stopped on test-completion

So, there are alternatives and hence any instruction "to drop schema in the “After” method i.e., after the test is completed" must be a recommendation, one which you are free to ignore as long as you are certain that you have *somehow* addressed the needs of test-independence.

Comment: Does this usually cause any problems during Jenkins Build i.e., if do not drop the schema after each test.

Comment: @ArunKumar That depends ... if you have only one test which uses HSQLDB then not cleaning up after this test cannot trip up any other tests but if you have numerous tests which use HSQLDB then the scope for issues is increased. The most common type of issue in this space is one of test-independence. So, in general, if you are concerend about this at all then you should just follow the standard advice and either (1) make your tests transactional or (2) drop (or at least truncate) the schema after every test.

Comment: One more question, when we run gradle build, each integration tests are executed. During these executions, is the JVM restarted for each integration test? Because if the JVM's are restarted, then the tables created by HSQLDB's should be dropped automatically. If not, then it makes sense to drop them. Please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: Do you have a particular preference to not drop the schema? If not, then just follow the convention. Re you question about Gradle, I suspect that depends on how you configure the integration test runner used by Gradle. You might also want to bear in mind that you won't necessarily always use Gradle so in order to ensure that your tests are independent of each other you should probably drop the schema (or make the tests transactional) explicitly rather than relying on a side effect of how you run the tests.

Comment: Yes I must see how the gradle is configured to know if the JVM is restarted or not. Anyway thanks a lot for everything.